# setState is updating css attribute for all elements in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm mapping through an array and creating `<li>` elements for each element of the array. There is also an `<img>` inside each `<li>` element which has a `display` attribute whose value is depending upon the `isDownloading` state object.

**The problem:**

Whenever I'm clicking an `<li>` element the images appear for all of the `<li>` elements instead of that particular `<li>` element.

**The code:**

```
...
constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = {data: null, isDownloading: null}
}

componentDidMount() {
  ...
  //array of data from api call
  this.setState({data: dataArray})
}

generateList = (data) => {
  const listElement = data.map((info, i) => {
    return (
      <li onClick={() => this.setState({isDownloading: true})} key={i}>Download<img style={{display: this.state.isDownloading ? 'inline-block' : 'none'}} src='loader.png' /></li>
    )
  }
  return listElement
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {this.generateList(this.state.data)} //renders 10 li elements
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
...
```

Comment: How are you linking your image tag and image data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because for **every** img you are doing this :

`style={{display: this.state.isDownloading ? 'inline-block' : 'none'}}`

You are referencing the same state for each image. If this.state.isDownloading **every** image's style will be : `{ 'inline-block'}` since this.state.isDownloading is true.

Now one way to display a loader per element is to update your state so that you will know if a download is happening (isDownloading) AND to which img it refers to. So you must track two things :

- is downloading ?
- which one is downloading ?

You can do that by updating your 'onClick' function, we can for exemple pass the 'key' props as an argument so that we know which li is being downloaded :

`<li onClick={() => this.setState({ isDownloading: true, keyItemBeingDownloaded: key})/>`

And now you can update your style's condition to this :

`this.state.isDownloading && key === this.state.keyItemBeingDownloaded`

So now, **if** isDownloading && **if** the item's key being downloaded corresponds to the item's key in the loop then display the loader.